# Taxonomy-Related news-block-portion disappear and reappear on Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, taxonomy

I have a block which displays all news belonging to terms of a category. However, sometimes, all news related to a term disappear while other terms' news are still visible. This disappear chunk appears on its own later. Is there a way I can fix it.

Both temporary or Permanent solutions are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

I have tried repairing tables, flushing cache but to no avail.

I checked the queries, they seem to be working fine.. I have used APC cache. Could that be a cause of old cached data. I tried flushing APC cache using apc_clear_cache() w and calling apc_clear_cache('user') but it hangs the server into indefinite loop.

Comment: this information is not enough to fix your problem

Comment: I checked the queries, they seem to be working fine.. I have used APC cache. Could that be a cause of old cached data. I tried flushing APC cache using apc_clear_cache() w and calling apc_clear_cache('user') but it hangs the server into indefinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem. The problem was that one of the news belonging to the set of news of a particular taxonomy was saved partially. Though there was an entry in the node table, other related data was missing.

On deleting this partial node manually from the database, the set of missing news articles reappeared.